# Why there's new entry after the if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    float radius;
    float keliling;
    float luas;
    const float PI = 3.14;
    char choice;
    luas = 0;
    keliling = 0;
    
    printf("Luas or Keliling :\n");
    scanf("%s", &choice);

    if(choice = luas){
        printf("Enter radius :\n");
        scanf("%f", &radius);
        keliling = 2 * PI * radius;
        luas = PI * pow(radius, 2);
        printf("Luas lingkaran adalah : %.2f\n", luas);
        
    }
    else if(choice = keliling){
        printf("Enter radius :\n");
        scanf("%f", &radius);
        keliling = 2 * PI * radius;
        luas = PI * pow(radius, 2);
        printf("Keliling lingkaran adalah : %.2f\n", keliling);
    }

    return 0;


}
```

when i run the code, the code goes to if statement for choose beetwen luas and keliling
and i choose luas
but after i choose luas, there's a new entry, and whatever i fill the entry with any word it goes"blablabla is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

try to find the error and fix the code

Comment: Please refresh what your beginners books or tutorials say about `=` and `==`. One is assignment, the other is comparison for equality. Also refresh what your beginners material say about comparing strings. And the `scanf` format `%s` compared to `%c`.

Comment: As noted by @Someprogrammerdude, the "=" problem ... AND `luas = 0; keliling = 0;` There is no difference between these two values. The `else` clause will never trigger because zero equals zero...

Comment: And right now the only difference between the two branches is the output. Perhaps you should think a bit more about what each branch should do, what separates them from each other. What parts should really be common. Perhaps you could do some common things outside the `if else`, and the specific different things inside.

Comment: Since both AREA and CIRCUMFERENCE are calculated in both branches of the `if()`, why not dispose of the schmozzle and simply calc and print both values?? Code that is not there cannot contribute bugs to the program...

Comment: can you guys give the "fixed" code so i can analyse the code and learn something about it

Comment: you wrote = instead of ==

Comment: You have *multiple* problems. The assignment with `=` instead of comparison with `==` is only a small problem, far from the worst. To me it seems like you have skipped way to much of your beginners material (books, tutorials or classes), or a simply trying to learn by guessing. Neither is a good way to learn programming. Please go back to the beginning of your books or tutorials and start over.

Comment: `if(choice = luas){` hmmm.... I'm not even sure what you are trying to do but this code assigns a float value to a char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that luas and keiling are floats and you are trying compare them with a string. Just like @Haris mentioned.

and `=` is assignment. you should use `==` to compare. Regardless you can also use `switch(choice)` if you want.

you should also take the radius scanning out of your if condition.
also in following code choice of luas is 0 and keliling is 1.
In enum if values are not explicitly mentioned it start from 0

A working version of your code will look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14

enum Choice {
    luas, /* Area of a circle  */   /* luas = 0 */
    keliling /* circumference of a circle */ /* keliling = 1 */
};

int main ( void ) {
    float radius;
    double result;
    int choice;

    printf("Luas or Keliling :\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    printf("Enter radius :\n");
    scanf("%f", &radius);

    switch(choice) {
        case luas:
        result = PI * pow(radius, 2);
        printf("Luas lingkaran adalah : %.2f\n", result);
        break;

        case keliling:
        result = 2 * PI * radius;
        printf("Keliling lingkaran adalah : %.2f\n", result);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for y'all, and i will take your advices guys

Comment: Pragmatic i tried to use your code, but it doesn't work too, why ??

Comment: It works for me. are you linking the math library ? if you are using the gcc compiler your compile command should look like this `gcc -o circle circle.c -lm` provided the name of the c file is circle.c

Comment: the math library is already existed in your code

Comment: No in my code math library header is included. but you have link the math library. Please check my last comment for clarification.

Comment: the math library is already existed in your code, and my compile is just "gcc -o circle.c circle" without -lm, what does -lm meaning ??

Comment: how to link the math library

Comment: `m` stands for math library. `-l` is link command. Therefore `-lm` means  link math library.

Comment: ahhh i see, i'm really thanks for your help, and please help me again when i need your help my bro

Answer (score 2):

### Assignment vs Comparison:

```
if(choice = luas)
```

This initializes `choice` —  which is of type `char` — with `luas`, which is of type `float`.

`=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison. That being said, you can't compare strings with `==`, use standard `strcmp`. `==` will only compare the pointer values.

### Incorrect format specifier:

```
scanf("%s", &choice);
```

This invokes undefined behaviour. `choice` is declared to be of type `char`. The correct format specifier for a `char` is `%c`.
But then you want the user to enter a string, so `scanf` will read one `char` and leave the trailing junk in the input buffer, which might automatically be read by subsequent calls to input functions, and you'll never be prompted for input.